# Applying Ito formula to the Brownian bridge

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion and
$$
W_t=(1-t)\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s}dB_s
$$
be a Brownian bridge.
Calculate $dW_t$.

To apply Ito formula define
$$
f(t,B_t)=(1-t) \int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}dB_s
$$
Then
\begin{align}
f_t(t,B_t)&=-\int_0^t\frac{1}{1-s}dB_s+(?) \\
f_{B_t}(t,B_t)&=(?) \\
f_{B_t,B_t}(t,B_t)&=(?)
\end{align}

What are the (?) and how do we get them?

Comment: You might want to define precisely what you call $\partial_{B_t}W_t$ in this context.

Comment: @did I precised the items. Thank you for pointing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's define $X_t = \int_0^t \frac{\mathrm{d}B_s}{1-s}$, which is to say $\mathrm{d}X_t = \frac{1}{1-t} \mathrm{d}B_t$. Its sde thus has zero drift coefficient.

Then we are faced with using Ito formula for $W_t = (1-t) X_t$.
$$
   \mathrm{d} W_t = \left(\frac{\partial ((1-t)X_t))}{\partial t} + \underbrace{0}_{\text{drift}} \frac{\partial ((1-t)X_t))}{\partial X_t} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{1-t}}_\text{diffusion}\right)^2 \underbrace{\frac{\partial^2 ((1-t)X_t))}{\partial X_t^2}}_0 \right) \mathrm{d}t + \frac{\partial ((1-t)X_t)}{\partial X_t} \mathrm{d}X_t
$$
Thus
$$
   \mathrm{d}W_t = -X_t  \mathrm{d}t + (1-t) \mathrm{d} X_t = -\frac{W_t}{1-t} \mathrm{d}t +  \mathrm{d} B_t
$$

Comment: Your answer smooth the trip from standard calculus to stochastic calculus. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to replicate your answer using a "long-hand" notation and although I get very close, I am still struggling to exactly replicate your result. If you take interest, I'd really appreciate if you could take a look at my related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967128/show-that-dx-t-fracx-t1-tdtdw-t-can-be-written-as-x-t-1-t-int-0t) and perhaps give me a hint where I might be going wrong? Thank you so much for your time and help.